# url rewriting without page name

Tags: c#, iis-6, url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5, url-routing

I want to route these 3 paths to default base url path.

```
www.mysite.com/page1.aspx
www.mysite.com/page2.aspx
www.mysite.com/page3.aspx
```

I want to appear these 3 pages in address bar like this: www.mysite.com

There are only these 3 pages in my asp.net project.

How can I do this in asp.net 3.5 sp1 with IIS 6.0.

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            switch (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower())
            { 
                case "/page1.aspx":
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/default.aspx");
                    break;                
                 case "/page2.aspx":
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/default.aspx");
                    break;                 
                 case "/page3.aspx":
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/default.aspx");
                    break;             
            }
  }
```

With this code, error occured:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /default.aspx
```

Problem is rewriting the url. It is searching default.aspx file. There is no default.aspx file. There is page1.aspx file.

Why it is searching default.aspx ? I just want to rewrite path..

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` is saying "if anyone asks for `/page1.aspx` (or `/page2.aspx`or `/page3.aspx`), serve them `~/default.aspx` instead".

Naturally if `~/default.aspx` doesn't exist, this will throw a 404.

What are you trying to do? You say you "want to route these 3 paths to default base url path" but what *is* that path if `~/default.aspx` doesn't exist?

Comment: I just want to rewrite the url, dont want to route another page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rewrite the url". Rewriting a URL means serving a page other than the physical page that the URL points to. What **exactly** do you want to happen when a user requests `http://www.mysite.com/page1.aspx` ?